# CSS/HTML Intellisense VS2012 - not showing all possibilities

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2012

I was just wondering, is there any way to improve the current VS2012 intellisense? I'm working on some HTML/CSS but it's not showing everything when i want a background-color it works fine, but when i start type rgb it doesn't show that opportunity.. so is there any add-in or something that i can do to improve it? - it's just nice to have when you are exploring HTML/CSS instead of looking at W3schools and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, people will probably shout at you for using W3schools. It has improved recently, but it still lists a lot of erroneous and insecure examples. If you want a HTML or CSS reference it's much better to rely on W3.org ([HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/HTML), [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/HTML5), [CSS(+3)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/)).

I'm not sure what you're using Visual Studio 2012 for, but when I work on ASP.NET projects I usually use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) for modifying HTML and CSS. I've found VS to be quite clunky when it comes to predicting things.

Either way, it's probably not best to *rely* on "Intellisense" for code help - you should use it as reference only, that way you'll learn to use the language independently.

Comment: Thanks! - i'll just use subline text for my HTML/CSS!

Comment: "you should use it as reference only" +1